r8169 ethernet link doesn't go up
Ethernet fails to connect. Green light is solid on the ethernet port. In the settings GUI it seems to recognize the cable is plugged in, but shows as "Connecting - 10 Mb/s" followed by a notification that the connection failed.
I verified that the cable and router are good by swapping my thinkpad for a raspberry pi (same router, same cable) which was able to access the internet fine.
Also, I tried connecting the laptop directly to the modem using the original modem<->router ethernet cable, and I got the same result.
ethtool -i enp5s0:

driver: r8169
version: 6.8.0-48-generic
firmware-version: rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:05:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no

dmesg | tail:
[ 2285.597350] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[ 2287.166386] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 2288.044704] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[ 2289.615486] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 2290.502541] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[ 2292.073327] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 2292.960715] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[ 2294.531417] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 2295.407810] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Down
[ 2297.029404] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: Link is Up - 10Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx

Thinkpad p14s gen1 amd / 24.04.1 LTS fresh install
I did come across this: https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Realtek_8169_driver_problem But I don't know if it's relevant
